# How do I set an Expires header on a response in ASP.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

In a controller action, returning an IActionResult, how do I set an expires header?

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/?view=aspnetcore-2.1), but it seems to relate to server side caching, not simply setting a response header. I feel this should be really straightforward !

Answer (score 8):

You can inside your contoller set the header:

```
string ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Response.Headers.Add("Expires", ExpireDate + " GMT");
```

Comment: I believe it is also possible to set the `Response.Headers.Expires` object directly instead of adding the header.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headers.responseheaders.expires?view=aspnetcore-6.0